# Setting Path on do file

Tags: file, path, stata

I am new to Stata, and I am trying to set the path to the file location. However, it kept giving me error

I tried to fix it by changing the backward/forward slash, but it still gives me this error. Does anyone know where I am wrong?

[image: 1]

Comment: Possibly a non-standard space imported from somewhere else.

Comment: If you are editing code in a word processor, it can use unusual space-like characters. Best to write code in a text editor, not least Stata's own `doedit`.

Comment: That error means Stata failed to recognize the command, program, or ado-file name, probably because of a typographical or abbreviation error. I am guessing this is because your cd has a colon and ends with a comma rather than a semi-colon. It should be -cd "C:/.../Lab1";-.